# Regular Expression for data packets from websockets

Tags: regex, csv

My application receives data packets from websockets. The data has some formats which give information about the data, examples are given below.

- Handshake    [0,"957529506107a4c7b3dba869424463",1,"Ratchet/0.3.6"]
- Event        [8,"316662",{"id":1115411,"side":"left"}]

I want regular expressions to identify the type of packet and the values of different segments.
Tried many regular expressions but not satisfied from them.

Update:
I tried with below code of .net but it gives false

```
Regex.IsMatch("[0,\"957529506107a4c7b3dba869424463\",1,\"Ratchet\\/ 0.3.6\"]", "/\\s*\\[(\\d+),\"([^\"]+)\", (\\d +),\"(.*?)\"\\]$");
```

Comment: What did you try for the moment?
And what type of data structure do we usually get? Is there other formats? we need more information about the data you recieve from the web sockets.

Comment: i tried to create different regexes but no luck, discarded them. These are 2 types of structures which solve my work :) others i don't need. for handshake message the stucture is first element to be an int, 2nd element to be string, 3rd element to be number again, and 4th string. similarly for Event we have number,string,json

Comment: Did my answer below help you?

Comment: yes, thanks . only the handshake and event captions were wrong but it was my mistake. The actual packets were the data with braces and text inside it. captions of handshake and event i just added in my question for differentiating. Anyhow i removed the captions from regular expressions and its fine, Thanks  again :)

Answer (score 1):

We could do one single regex to match both of them but as the structure is different I propose you use one regex for each case, so that you can know which one your matching.

#### For the *Handshake*

I would use this regex (with the case insensitive flag):

```regex
/^handshake\s*\[(\d+),"([^"]+)",(\d+),"(.*?)"\]$/i
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/u17G7y/1

Explanation:

- `^handshake\s*` matches only if it starts with `handshake` and some optional spaces.
- `\[` to match the opening bracket.
- `(\d+)` matches the digits and captures it.
- `"([^"]+)"` will match and capture the string that contains any char except quotes.
- `"(.*?)"` is a bit similar but in a different approach. It captures the string between the quotes by matching any char in an ungreedy way. This is because I don't know if the string itself may contain an escaped quote, such as `"Some \"quotes\" in the string"`.
- `\]$` matches a clothing bracket and the end of the string.

#### For the *Event*

I would use this regex (with the case insensitive flag):

```regex
/^event\s*\[(\d+),"([^"]+)",(\{.*\})\]$/i
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/mZ6V5D/1

The only difference is that we've got 3 elements to capture instead of 4 and
that we'll have to capture in a greedy way between the `{` and `}` chars as we don't know if the object contains other objects. This is why I used `(\{.*\})` and not `(\{.*?\})`.

#### If you can only have one regex

In this case, you could put both regex together with the `(?:AAA|BBB)` syntax, where `AAA` is the *Handshake* pattern and `BBB` the *Event* pattern. This leads to this regex:

```regex
/^(?:handshake\s*\[(\d+),"([^"]+)",(\d+),"(.*?)"|event\s*\[(\d+),"([^"]+)",(\{.*\}))\]$/i
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/srzJw7/1

Comment: your solution works in the link you provided but when i run it in .net with below source code it returns false 
Regex.IsMatch("[0,\"957529506107a4c7b3dba869424463\",1,\"Ratchet\\/ 0.3.6\"]", "/\\s*\\[(\\d+),\"([^\"]+)\", (\\d +),\"(.*?)\"\\]$")